How a Kafka consumer asyncCommit is asynchronous on a single thread
As I know Kafka consumer is not thread safe. So how can asyncCommit be asynchronous if it uses one main application thread?
The documentation is unclear about this. I expect that asyncCommit must be run on a different thread, otherwise it can't be asynchronous.

It is executed on a different thread. Record fetching and heartbeats happen on different threads too.

@OneCricketeer thank you very much for the clarification. Does it use one thread or multiple?
